# Grep all lines with exactly one instance of a specific character

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I want to grep all lines with only one "#" in a line.

Example:

```
xxx#aaa#iiiii
xxxxxxxxx#aaa
#xxx#bbb#111#yy
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx#
xxx#x
#x#v#e#
```

Should give this output

```
xxxxxxxxx#aaa
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx#
xxx#x
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try

```
grep '^[^#]*#[^#]*$' file
```

where

```
^      ; begin of line
[^#]*  ; any number of char ≠ #
#      ; #
[^#]*  ; any number of char ≠ #
$      ; end of line
```

as sugested, you can grep on the whole line, with

```
grep -x '[^#]*#[^#]*'
```

with

- same pattern without begin of line/end of line anchor.
- `-x` to grep whole line, see `man grep`

> ```
> -x, --line-regexp
>    Select  only  those  matches  that  exactly  match  the  whole line.  For a regular
>    expression pattern, this is like parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it
>    with ^ and $.
> ```

Answer (score 15):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'#' 'NF==2' infile
```

based on `#` field separator, if number of fields in a line was exactly two fields then will print out. note that for example `#x` or `x#` or even `#` are considered two fields so.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110280/discussion-on-answer-by-s-grep-all-lines-with-exactly-one-instance-of-a-spe).

Answer (score 10):

With two calls to `grep`: pick any line that has at least one `#`, then remove those that have at least two:

```
grep '#' filename | grep -v '#.*#'
```

Comment: The second regexp can be simplified to `'#.*#'`.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU grep:

```
$ grep -P '^(?!(?:.*#){2}).*#' infile
xxxxxxxxx#aaa
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx#
xxx#x
$
```

The  -P option means use PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) regex. See https://www.pcre.org. PCRE are extensions to ERE (Extended Regular Expressions), originally introduced into Perl, which were later adopted by many commands, utilities, applications and programming languages.

If GNU grep is not available on your platform, you can install `pcregrep` which is part of the `pcre-tools` package that is available on many platforms.

The generalized form of this particular PCRE regex is:

```
^(?!(?:.*PATTERN){2}).*PATTERN
```

where `PATTERN` stands for the pattern that you want to occur once and only once in the grepped string. In our case the pattern is `#`.

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?!(?:.*PATTERN){2})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match that is immediately to the right of the current location, i.e. the start of string, if there are two (`{2}`) consecutive occurrences of:

  - `.*` - 0 or more characters
  - `PATTERN` - the pattern
- `.*` - 0 or more characters
- `PATTERN` - the pattern

Comment: Ahhhh... Million times thanks!!! I wasn't aware about the "p" option.

Comment: would you care to explain the regex ?

Comment: and THAT is the main problem with `-P` - something that's trivial and obvious in a BRE or ERE becomes convoluted runes in a PCRE. The other 2 problems are that it's only available in GNU grep so it's not portable, and its still experimental and doesn''t play well with other grep options (per the GNU grep man page).

Comment: @EdMorton.  Actually, the current `grep` manpage states that -P is "experimental  when  ***combined***  with  the  -z  (--null-data)  option,  and  grep -P may warn of unimplemented features."  Other than `-z` option, the manpage does not state any other options that `-P` "doesn''t play well with".  What other grep options are you aware of that `-P` is problematic with?

Comment: @EdMorton, and some other things are impossible in BRE and ERE, but possible in PCRE, or at least made simpler in it. It's not a problem with `-P` or PCRE, but with how to use them.

Comment: @fpmurphy I know the man page changed recently from saying `This is highly experimental` (e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to `experimental when combined with the -z` but  I wouldn't consider using `-P` as long as the man page refers to it as experimental in any context (why should using NUL instead of `\n` as the terminating char make any difference in reasonably written software and how do they **know** that's the **only** thing impacted), and so I'm sorry but I can't provide insight on what the `unimplemented features` might be that it will apparently warn you about or other issues.

Comment: @ilkkachu right but if a task is too complicated to handle in a BRE or ERE then that doesn't mean a PCRE is the best way to handle it - [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: @EdMorton How do you match a palindrome in BRE or ERE ? How do you match nested parenthesis in BRE or ERE ?  Too complex? Let's try a simpler one: How do you ensure that there is no `foo` following a match **without also matching the foo** ?

Comment: @Isaac I'm not saying it's possible to, nor that you need to, perform all tasks using a single regular expression. What I was pointing out above is that something trivial and obvious became convoluted enough when written as a PCRE that it inspired a request for explanation that's been upvoted by 7 people so far, unlike any of the other solutions posted. Feel free to ask a question if you have one, make sure to include a MCVE with concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: But you do say: *if a task is too complicated to handle in a BRE or ERE then that doesn't mean a PCRE is the best way to handle it*. And. in the three examples I provided, a PCRE is not only the best way but the only way to match with a regex. I suggest that you may benefit from being more open to alternative solutions. @EdMorton

Comment: @Isaac but that's assuming I'd want to tackle that problem with a regexp when in fact I'm more open to an alternative solution that can be implemented using standard UNIX tools, none of which support PCREs. If you'd like to see a solution that I'd use, again please do feel free to post a question.

Comment: What is not nice is to say: "becomes convoluted runes in a PCRE". Which, besides not being true (I can read that perfectly fine), it is like saying: I wont learn the new ciphers (Hindu-Arabic numeral system) because I know my roman numerals perfectly well. @EdMorton

Comment: @EdMorton, for a moment I thought that Atwood blog entry was about trying to parse HTML with regex, which is just stupid(*). But that seems to be actually a rather simple pattern, just with a long list of alternations. Would probably be better written as `</?($foo)>` (where `$foo` is some method of inserting the list of words joined with `|`) or something in that direction (I'm not going to test it now). That can be done with PCRE or ERE, it should be about the same length in either.

Comment: @EdMorton, but PCRE does have some useful things that aren't readily available in ERE, at least non-greedy matching (`.*?`) and word border matches come to mind (`\b`). Look-aheads are also sometimes useful, but here it's just an overcomplicated way of doing that. And that's not because it's PCRE, but because they chose an overcomplicated way in stead of the straightforward. (Sorry, fpmurphy.) Though of course ERE would allow much fewer possibilities for such non-straightforward solutions, so there's that.

Comment: (* since I mentioned parsing HTML, and Isaac also mentioned nested parenthesis and other stuff that's beyond actual regular languages, I just have to link this here: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Regexp-Grammars/lib/Regexp/Grammars.pm . I'll leave it to everyone to decide if they want to use Perl REs, or e.g. yacc/bison the next time they need an actual parser.)

Comment: @fpmurphy Wouldn't it be simpler to use: `grep -P '^[^#]*#(?!.*#)' infile`. In words: match the first `#` provided that (the lookahead) no other `#` exists ?

Comment: @Isaac Yes. That is another approach that works well.

Comment: @Isaac, incidentally that's just about the same as the ERE in [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596454/170373). This problem isn't much if a showcase for the usefulness of PCRE. :) PCRE might start to be more useful than ERE if the question was about a separator longer than one character. (On the other hand, if we had the the whole Perl language at hand, we could do something other than regex-optimizing too.)

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` we can use the gsub function in the condition block to select our lines :

```
$ awk 'gsub(/#/, "#") == 1' file

$ awk '/#/ && ! /#.*#/' file 

$ sed -ne 's/#/&/2;t' -e '//p' file
```

- Lines with atleast 2 `#` will not be printed due to the `t` command  and `-n` option given to sed.
- That leaves us with lines either with exactly one # or none. Print he former with //

With `perl` we can count the number of `#` chars in a scalar context to detect our lines :

```
$ perl -ne 'print if tr/#/#/ == 1'  file
```

Answer (score -1):

command

```
awk '{print $0,gsub("#",$1)}' filename |awk '$NF == "1"'
```

output

```
xxxxxxxxx#aaa 1
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx# 1
xxx#x 1
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    if i.count("#") == 1:
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
xxxxxxxxx#aaa
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx#
xxx#x
```

Comment: Please let me know the reason for downvote

Comment: I'm not down-voter, but for `awk` which I know a bit how it works, you just overkill the [`awk 'gsub(/#/, "#") == 1' file` command given answer by **Rakesh Sharma** above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596620/72456). I don't know python at all for that part.

Comment: Thanks for input and suggestion